# Is it possible to autoload a file based on the namespace in PHP?

Tags: php, python, module, namespaces, autoload

Would what mentioned in the title be possible? Python module style that is. See this example for what I exactly mean.

#### index.php

```
<?php
use Hello\World;
World::greet();
```

#### Hello/World.php

```
<?php
namespace Hello\World;
function greet() { echo 'Hello, World!'; }
```

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, have a look at the example of [spl_autoload_register](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

```
namespace Foobar;

class Foo {
    static public function test($name) {
        print '[['. $name .']]';
    }
}

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo::test'); // As of PHP 5.3.0

new InexistentClass;
```

> The above example will output something similar to:

```
[[Foobar\InexistentClass]]
Fatal error: Class 'Foobar\InexistentClass' not found in ...
```

---

Here is a link to a [Autoloader builder](http://github.com/theseer/Autoload), that

> is a command line application to automate the process of generating an autoload include file.

Comment: So it seems it's only possible to do with classes. I'll just have to live with that :)